# When to use ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService() vs just the class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

My `Startup.ConfigureServices()` looks like this:

```
...
services
.AddSingleton(x =>
                {
                    IConnectionMultiplexer connection = ...
                    string keyPrefix = ...
                    return new RedisSessionService(connection, keyPrefix);
                })
.AddSingleton<ITicketStore>(x => x.GetRequiredService<RedisSessionService>())
.AddSingleton<ISessionService>(x => x.GetRequiredService<RedisSessionService>())
.AddSingleton<ILookupNormalizer, LowerInvariantLookupNormalizer>()
...
```

`RedisSessionService` implements both `ITicketStore` (from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies` namespace) and `ISessionService` (my own interface).

If I use this instead:

```
.AddSingleton<ITicketStore, RedisSessionService>()
.AddSingleton<ISessionService, RedisSessionService>()
```

I get:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to
> activate
> 'MyNamespace.IdentityServer4.Server.Services.RedisSessionService'.

Why do I need to use `GetRequiredService()` in this instance?

When are you meant to use `GetRequiredService()` vs `AddSingleton<ISomeInterface, SomeClass>()`

Comment: There must be something like; `.AddSingleton<RedisSessionService>(_ => new RedisSessionService(...))`. Your `.AddSingleton<ITicketStore>(x => x.GetRequiredService<...` code will ensure that only one instance of the singleton is created. If you use `.AddSingleton<ITicketStore, RedisSessionService>()` then the constructor must include only services, and you would create more than one instance of the service.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I've updated my question. I think if I understand correctly, the first call to `AddSingleton()` sets up the `RedisSessionService` instance, then in order to access that instance, you need to use `GetRequiredService()`. Is that right?

Comment: If a service uses `RedisSessionService` as a dependency, then everything is fine. If a service uses `ITicketStore` as a dependency *and* you want to ensure there's only one instance of the singleton, then `.AddSingleton<ITicketStore>(x => x.GetRequiredService<RedisSessionService>())` ensures that the interface is an alias to the same instance.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman if you write that up as an answer I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, there is an argument of type string in the constructor of your `RedisSessionService`.

When it tries to create an instance of `RedisSessionService`, it couldn't find service type of string in `IServiceProvider` to construct the instance. Then you registered an instance of `RedisSessionService` and registered services as you mentioned:

```
.AddSingleton<ITicketStore>(x => x.GetRequiredService<RedisSessionService>())
.AddSingleton<ISessionService>(x => x.GetRequiredService<RedisSessionService>())
```

If I misunderstood you, please point out.

And in fact, to fix the error you've shown, you could also just try to add

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(x => "the string argument");
```

Last but not least, it's more recommended to try with [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0) instead of adding string parameter in the constructor